# Angular build breaks when using --prod-flag

Tags: angular, build, angular2-aot

My Angular 4 build using angular-cli runs through and I can start the app, but a lot of components do not load properly. My console is filled with these error messages:

```
Expected function name "for", was ""
Expected function name "keyFor", was ""
Expected function name "next", was ""
Expected function name "next", was ""
Expected function name "clear", was ""
Expected function name "delete", was ""
Expected function name "entries", was ""
Expected function name "forEach", was ""
Expected function name "get", was ""
Expected function name "has", was ""
Expected function name "keys", was ""
Expected function name "set", was ""
Expected function name "values", was ""
Expected function name "next", was ""
Expected function name "add", was ""
Expected function name "clear", was ""
Expected function name "delete", was ""
Expected function name "entries", was ""
Expected function name "forEach", was ""
Expected function name "has", was ""
Expected function name "values", was ""
Expected function name "next", was ""
Expected function name "delete", was ""
Expected function name "get", was ""
Expected function name "has", was ""
Expected function name "set", was ""
Expected function name "add", was ""
Expected function name "delete", was ""
Expected function name "has", was ""
Expected function name "all", was ""
Expected function name "race", was ""
Expected function name "reject", was ""
Expected function name "resolve", was ""
Expected function name "catch", was ""
Expected function name "then", was ""
```

Anyone with an idea where to start to track this down?

Comment: Are you using angular-cli?

Comment: yes, sorry forgot that. I'll edit it in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is twofold, the errors I posted in the question refer to a polyfill I loaded (and apparently shouldn't): *js-polyfills* after removing this from my *polyfills.ts* the errors disappear.

This did not solve the bugs in my app however. After some more testing I found the problem lying in me using `someObject.constructor.name === 'someString'`. The angular-cli-compiler runs *UglifyJS* after the build process and hence changes class- and therefore constructor names. Replacing this with an explicit `type`-field in the class resolved the errors I experienced. Also see: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5168